# How Communication is done between angular 2 components over Web between 2 diff browsers / 2 different users?

Tags: angular

This is wat my problem is :
I have 2 components in angular 2 app - 1 to view items - 2nd for adding items. if 2 users access my app- 1 user adds item. Meanwhile 2nd user is viewing items. Wat is best way to show newly added item to 2nd user without refreshing his entire view?

Comment: The most efficient way would be to use something like websockets. A less efficient way would be to use polling

Answer (score 0):

Angular is not enough at scale in this case, it needs network and backend "actions" like giving for each user a specific communication port, jobs listening to updates. You could achieve this using something like ExpressJs + MongoDB (a tuto exists on it)

For the angular part, you need to create :

- a user / auth service get the updates from a REST endpoint using http
- in this service, an Observable / Behavior Subject to subscribe to the updates on the frontend, and POST it to your endpoint
- and finally get the updated result in your POST response if success or every 2 second using :

  Observable.interval(2000).subscribe(() => {
          getUpdate();
      });

Answer (score 0):

What you want is real time application.
You can follow [link](https://www.genuitec.com/realtime-server-monitoring-app-angular-4-node-js-chart-js/), [Real time application](https://hackernoon.com/build-real-time-app-with-mean2-angular-cli-and-socket-io-cedf1dc02fec) to get some more clarity and get on the right path to achieve what you are looking for.